# customize Windows MSI installer screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

Creating MSI using visual studio 2013.

Want to make changes to welcome screen,installation and confirm installation screen which has some default layout and only able to make minor changes like updating the text.Is it possible to customize the screen.
Their is option to add Dialog option which is also customizable to some extent.
So please suggest.

Comment: I have used ORCA to make customizations in the past. It is Microsofts msi editor.

Answer (score 1):

There's no support for this in Visual Studio - you'd need to do as Mark Hall suggests in his comment, or some other similar tool like InstEdit. They typically require you to know something about the internals of MSI files. If you expect to eventually create more and more custom dialogs you should choose a tool that allows that with IDE support.